# Prematurely closing a PDO connection passed to objects not working

Tags: php, class, pdo, null

K I am passing a PDO connection to a class constructor to get some sql information. It works perfectly when I don't manually close the PDO with NULL.

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test');
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage();
}

$objGetReference = new getReference($dbh);
$reference=$objGetReference->getReference();
```

However, when I have the exact same code with a $dbh=null; at the end to close the pdo object it fails. So the following does not work:

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test');
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage();
}

$objGetReference = new getReference($dbh);
$reference=$objGetReference->getReference();

$dbh=NULL;
```

I know the php script will kill it anyway when it finishes, I want to end it like this though. Just good habit.

How do I close the database connection early?

Also if I pass it to multiple classes, should I close it individually inside each class that uses it?

Thanks all.

Comment: I tried to comprehend the problem, but failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to terminate the execution of the script, you can use [die](http://php.net/die) or [exit](http://php.net/exit) with an optional error message that will be presented to the user.

According to the [PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php):

> To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring
>   that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by
>   assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object

It is worded a bit wrong (at least to me), because not only do you need to destroy all references, but you also need to destroy all copies too.

For example:

```
$a = new PDO( [args] );
$b = $a;
$a = null;
```

Then `$b` is still connected to the database, so you have to make sure that you destroy it as well. This is also true for using it as an argument of a method/function since this creates a copy of the original object instead of a reference (unless passed by reference):

```
function killDbh($dbh) {
    $dbh = null;
}
killDbh($dbh);
echo get_class($dbh); // echoes PDO
```

In order to close the connection, you would need to close all connections, including any in objects. However, if you do,

```
$a = new PDO( [args] );
$b =& $a;
$a = null;
```

Then `$b` is a reference of `$a` and it will also be destroyed. Essentially, there is no *true* way to close the connection of a PDO object (like [mysqli_close](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)) aside from upon script termination because there is no way to set the object to a "disconnected" state, so any copies of the object are still connected.

In my experience, it is very seldomly necessary to explicitly close a database connection anyway, so you have little to worry about.

Comment: k thanks, so if I got to make all objects using the connection NULL I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine to close a PDO connection in this way.  You should describe more clearly what you mean by "does not work."

I would guess you are setting $dbh to null, but then trying to use it in a subsequent line of code.

To confirm this, I would make sure that my classes expecting a PDO object get one instead of null.  For example, use a **type hint**:

```
class getReference {
  public function __construct(PDO $dbh) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This is easy to do, and should make the constructor throw a fatal error if you accidentally pass a null.

```
$dbh = null
$r = new getReference($dbh);
```

Here's the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to getReference::__construct() 
must be an instance of PDO, null given
```